# ImageView Force closes my application

Tags: android, imageview

Hi there I am really a beginner, and I have been fighting with this problem for 3 days. :(

I am able to get an image to show using a grid view and an adapter as in the grid view tutorial, but I wanted to be able to just  use ImageView in the xml.

```
public class HelloImage extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView gridview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        gridview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        gridview.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        gridview.setImageResource(R.drawable.hand_tool);
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation = "horizontal"> 

    <ImageView    
        android:id ="@+id/gridview"   
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this it causes the app to force close when loading.

**EDIT by kcoppock: Transferring LogCat data from comments to post**

0

```
1-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61): + android 
01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61): + com.android.inputmethod.latin 
01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61): + com.android.browser 
01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61): + com.android.providers.userdictionary
01-15 14:59:24.961: INFO/BackupManagerService(61): + com.android.providers.settings 
For "Exception": 14:59:23.832: ERROR/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException 
14:59:36.361: WARN/Checkin(103): Can't update stat PHONE_GSM_REGISTERED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats 
14:59:38.951: WARN/Checkin(103): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_ATTEMPTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats 
14:59:39.991: WARN/NotificationService(61): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000 
01-15 14:59:40.001: WARN/Checkin(103): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_CONNECTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats 
01-15 15:40:40.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(128): ERROR: thread attach failed 
01-15 15:40:44.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): ERROR: thread attach failed
```

Comment: it's huge I don't know where to start and end :/ The only dark read error was Error: Thread attach failed would that be the culprit?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Or the terminal/command line?

Comment: If your activity crashes, in your log must be at least one exception, search for the red font(in DDMS), or copy/paste your entire log, and search 'exception'.

Comment: Then any block of red text as @fiction said. Or create a filter (+ symbol on the LogCat window) and filter by Log level (Error)

Comment: I don't think I understand how to filter it. When I put "+" in the filter the following errors show up:01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61):     + android
01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61):     + com.android.inputmethod.latin
01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61):     + com.android.browser
01-15 14:59:24.952: INFO/BackupManagerService(61):     + com.android.providers.userdictionary
01-15 14:59:24.961: INFO/BackupManagerService(61):     + com.android.providers.settings

Comment: For "Exception":
14:59:23.832: ERROR/System(61): java.lang.SecurityException
14:59:36.361: WARN/Checkin(103): Can't update stat PHONE_GSM_REGISTERED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
14:59:38.951: WARN/Checkin(103): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_ATTEMPTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats
14:59:39.991: WARN/NotificationService(61): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000

Comment: 01-15 14:59:40.001: WARN/Checkin(103): Can't update stat PHONE_GPRS_CONNECTED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/stats

Comment: Do you have a ContentProvider or are attemping to connect to EDGE/3G?

Comment: @BlueFireLady: What you have listed here is not your error. Get your "force close" to occur again. Scroll to the bottom of LogCat in DDMS. Work your way back up to the first Java stack trace (shown in red). Highlight the lines and press the disk icon in the DDMS LogCat toolbar to save them to a file. Open that file, then copy and paste the errors into your question (by editing it), formatted as source code (the pair of curly braces).

Comment: I'm so noob I don't even understand what that (ContentProvider or are attemping to connect to EDGE/3G) means... I have the out the box AVD you set up with the tutorials I was going through the tutorials and wanted to put an image on my screen that's not in a grid view.

Comment: OK CommonsWare this is what I get:
01-15 15:40:40.929: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(128): ERROR: thread attach failed
01-15 15:40:44.269: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(212): ERROR: thread attach failed

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You got ClassCastException on

```
gridview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

EDIT: And please, read how to use DDMS and LogCat!

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you mean by "I wanted to be able to just use ImageView in the XML", but if what you're wanting is a GridView, you have a lot of things out of whack there. You have an ImageView in your XML that you've named gridview -- it's not a gridview, but you're calling it one, you're just begging for confusion. It's like saying `int myString = 9;`.

Your second (related) problem, is that you're trying to set GridView.LayoutParams parameters to an ImageView inside a LinearLayout. You should be using LinearLayout.LayoutParams. And rather than doing that in code, why not just use XML?:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/hand_tool"
    />
```